# Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nodes

'Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future ...' this warning on front end show response error 500 and don't complete process after that 99.7%  can you explane what is the issue and warning show into added image

[attache below image describe error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SjJ9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the code I'm pretty sure that you are missing a catch on a promise somewhere. This is bad practice. You can easily fix it by catching the error, which will also help you debug if something goes wrong

example:

```
// Probably your code
SomePromise()
    .then(someResult => someHandler(someResult))


// Catching the error
SomePromise()
    .then(someResult => someHandler(someResult))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```